# save images inside div as one image

Tags: html

I have a div inside a webpage, below that div there are some images that you can select.
When you select an image you can place it inside the div by clicking on the div.This is working fine.

When someone puts some images inside the div and is done with it, I would like it to be able to save the content of the div, so to save all the images on the position as they were placed, and to merge it into to one image.

Is this possible if so, how could I do something like that?
At the moment I place the images with jQuery inside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one image of it is more complicated, you might wanna check http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ for that. You can also use a `canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `canvas`, then draw images onto it, then convert to an image and save. [This](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) might help. It will only work in browsers which have `canvas` support.